# postgres - empty query result when run in node/express (res.rows) but data returned fine when manually queried

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I'm having an issue with a query not returning any data in my node/express application (postgres db) when testing with postman, but when I run the below sql query in psql terminal, or another program (dbvisualizer) the results are output perfectly. When testing with postman I get a 200 back, with an empty object, so there's no communication issues, it's just that no data is returned.

```
app.get('/orgVendor2', (request, response, next) => {
  pool.query('SELECT o.organisation_name AS "org", STRING_AGG(v.name, ', ') AS "ven" FROM vendor v JOIN organisation o ON v.id_organisation = o.organisation_id GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1', (err, res) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    response.json(res.rows);
  });
});
```

I don't know why it won't work. If I replace the sql query with something simple like 'select * from organisation', then hit localhost:3000/orgVendor2 with postman I get a full response back as expected. I think the issue is either that node doesn't like the query for some reason, or res.rows isn't able to parse the response, even though it's just two columns of data, with several hundred rows.

Comment: I ended up working around it by adding a view of that sql query, then simply getting all data from the view, no idea why node doesn't like that query.

Comment: What you posted should throw a syntax error in my view, because of your usage a single quote in a literal that is also inside single quotes.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? I've tried multiple combinations of ' and " but I still can't get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is using quotes inside quotes - that is, the query you pass is the following:

```
'SELECT o.organisation_name AS "org", STRING_AGG(v.name, '
```

What your framework does with the rest (that is, `, ') AS "ven" FROM vendor v JOIN organisation o ON v.id_organisation = o.organisation_id GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1'` ), maybe interpreting it as a second parameter to `pool.query()`, I cannot tell.  However, Postgres has a solution for such cases - it's called dollar quoting, and the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) describes it and its use cases and advantages nicely.

In your case, modify your query literal to the following (line breaks added for readability):

```
SELECT o.organisation_name AS "org", STRING_AGG(v.name, $$, $$) AS "ven" 
  FROM vendor v 
  JOIN organisation o ON v.id_organisation = o.organisation_id 
 GROUP BY 1 
 ORDER BY 1'
```